# Convert wav to flv using speex codec

Tags: flash, ffmpeg, flv, wav, speex

How can I convert a `wav` file to an `flv`, resampling to a rate of 11kHz, and encoded with speex?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using ffmpeg. Speex is in the list of [ffmpeg's supported audio codecs](http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#Audio-Codecs). You will need to compile ffmpeg with `--enable-libspeex` added to the configure flags, or you can try finding a precompiled version that has libspeex support added.

Ffmpeg builds are available at [zeranoe.com](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), and this is their [latest build for windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ffmpeg-20120804-git-f857465-win32-static.7z) (it has speex support).

Your command line should be something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i myinputfile.wav -acodec libspeex -ar 11025 myoutputfile.flv
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04's ffmpeg is libspeex-enabled.